# What CPU is Azure App Service running on?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

What processor is Microsoft App Service V1 running on?

V2 seems to be running on Dv2-series VMs:

"The new Premium V2 tier features Dv2-series VMs with even faster processors, SSD storage, and double the memory-to-core ratio compared to the previous compute iteration."
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-app-service-premium-v2-in-public-preview/

However, what is the corresponding VM, CPU or performance of the previous compute iteration?
What would (roughly) be the CPU performance difference between P1 and P1V2 (or for example between a 4-core P3 and a 2-core P2V2)?

[image]
[image]

**Edit** According to this article - https://cloudspectator.com/microsoft-azure-dv2-vs-ds-comparison/ - Dv2 would be roughly 35% faster than Dv1 which would be roughly 60% faster than A (https://cloudspectator.com/wp-content/uploads/report/generational-performance-comparison-microsoft-azures-a-series-and-d-series.pdf) which is used in the V1 app services as stated in the accepted answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basic, Standard and Premium V1(including V1 App Service Environments) run on A series VM's.

Premium V2 and Isolated Sku(App Servicement Environment V2) run on Dv2 series machines.

Comment: Do you know if there is public documentation, blog posts etc about this available?

Comment: Not sure if there is anything documented but I work on the app service team so I can definitely tell you that’s what it is :)

Comment: In USD, the P1V2 plan and S2 plan are now the same price. Coming from an S1 plan, I naturally upgraded to the S2 plan. But is there any reason to choose the S2 over the P1V2?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone considering Azure Service Plan and confused to use A-Series (S,S2,S3) or Dv2-Series (P1V2, P2V2, P3V2), should consider Dv2-Series.
In Simple Dv2-Series are said to be double or more resources (CPU, RAM and storage) and better performance. Please refer to article [Announcing pricing decrease for Azure App Service on the Premium plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/announcing-pricing-decrease-for-azure-app-service-on-the-premium-plan/) for more details.

> With the new price reduction, it is more economical from a performance perspective (and more powerful!) to run a P1v2 App Service plan rather than an S1 App Service plan. This is also true for the other size plans when moving from S2 > P2v2 and S3 > P3v2, with each providing double the performance and memory of the comparable Standard plan. This can be seen in the green arrows in the image above.